# How to get the index of a Pandas series

Tags: pandas

`s` is of `type` `Series`:

```
print(type(s))

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print(s)

Date
2022-06-03    145.380005
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

I am iterating over a `rolling` calculation:

```
resampleStr = '180D'
dfRollSeries = df['Close'].rolling(resampleStr)
for s in dfRollSeries:
```

if I say

```
s.iat[0]
```

I get the `Close`

If I say

```
s.index
```

I get

```
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>
```

How do I get the value of the `index`? I need the `Date` part, `2022-06-03`?

Comment: added a solution, try it and its simple

Answer (score 0):

the `reset_index()` method ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html#pandas.Series.reset_index)) should do the trick, it will return the index of the series or dataframe.

`s.reset_index()['Date']`

To return as a string, you could do:
`s.reset_index()['Date'].iloc[0]`

Or depending on the size of the series you could get all the values as a list and iterate through as needed:

`s.reset_index()['Date'].values.tolist()` (All values)

`s.reset_index()['Date'].unique().tolist()` (Unique values)

Comment: Thanks that got me further, but this is the value I get: Roll Date 0   2022-06-03
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: For the love of God, I just need the " 2022-06-03" part. Pandas sucks

Comment: So is the expected output the first date value as a string, or are you creating a list of date values?

Comment: Just the date value as a string

Comment: I would look into loc and iloc functions: `s.reset_index()['Date'].iloc[0]` if you just want the first value, or replace the 0 with whatever index you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

this will get you the value of the index, i.e., the date

```
s.index[0]
```

Comment: @Ivan, did this solution worked for you?